# old values in pList file get overwritten

Tags: iphone, plist

Hello there I'm trying to create a dictionary with with phone numbers and I can populate the dictionary and add it to a plist but when I try to add to the plist again I overwrite the file.

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()
{
    NSMutableDictionary *NameNumberDict;
    NSDictionary *plistDict;
    NSMutableArray *numberArray;
    NSString *filePath;
}

@end

@implementation FirstViewController
@synthesize NameTxtField;
@synthesize FirstNumField;
@synthesize SecNumField;
@synthesize personName;
@synthesize phoneNumbers;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //get some memory 
    plistDict = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
    NameNumberDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    //make a file path string 
    NSArray *pathArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [pathArray objectAtIndex:0];
    filePath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];

    NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // here i set the Dictionary to the file

    //give the file to my dictonary
    NameNumberDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSLog(@"The count: %i", [NameNumberDict count]);

    //make sure the file is there
    NSString *err = nil;
    NSData *plist;
    plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:NameNumberDict format:NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&err];

    if([manager fileExistsAtPath:@"data.plist"] == NO)
    {
        [manager createFileAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"data.plist"] contents:plist attributes:nil];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setNameTxtField:nil];
    [self setFirstNumField:nil];
    [self setSecNumField:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

// Populate the dictionary when they dismiss the keyboard if all the data is filled out

-(IBAction)TextFieldReturn:(id)TextField
{
    if(!NameTxtField.text && !FirstNumField.text && !SecNumField.text);
    {
        NSString *name = NameTxtField.text;

        numberArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [numberArray addObject:FirstNumField.text];
        [numberArray addObject:SecNumField.text];

        [NameNumberDict setObject:name forKey:@"Name"];
        [NameNumberDict setObject:numberArray forKey:@"Number"];

        NSLog(@"dicSave: %@",NameNumberDict);
    }

    [TextField resignFirstResponder];
}

// and down here is where im lost Im not sure how to append the data to the Dictionary and write it to file

- (IBAction)AddBtn:(UIButton *)sender
{
    plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:NameNumberDict];

    [plistDict writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

    NSLog (@"File %@ exists on iPhone",filePath);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your "`TextFieldReturn`" method, I see you're always resetting the "`Name`" and "`Number`" objects of your "`NameNumberDict`" mutable dictionary each time it's being called.

I think what you really want to do is add a new dictionary (for each new name & number) to a mutable array and then write that mutable array out to a file (which would end up being your property list file).

Also, just as a style note: Method names and variable names should always start with a lowercase letter (e.g. "`textFieldReturn`", "`addBtn`", "`nameNumberDict`", etc.) while class names (e.g. "`FirstViewController`") are what start capitalized.